# Birthdays in iOS address book (contacts) with New Zealand timezone

Tags: ios, timezone, contacts, addressbook

I have this weird issue with birthday dates retrieved from the address book when the timezone is set to new zealand. 
When I format the date using a NSDateFormatter it shows the wrong date (always plus one day).

So I have a ABRecordRef and get the birthday date like this:

```
NSDate *birthday = objc_unretainedObject(ABRecordCopyValue(record,
                                                             kABPersonBirthdayProperty));
```

Now to get a localized string of the date I make this:

```
NSString *s = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:birthday dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

The birthday of the contact for example is 5 October 1975 (it's displayed like this in the contact details in the address book), but the code above produces 6/10/1975
It's always one day late. And it seems to happen only when I set the timezone to new zealand. I tried it on a device, set timezone to new zealand and this happens, or even in the iPhone simulator when I set the timezone of my mac to New Zealand.

Would greatly appreciate any feedback or help about this, I'm not sure if I ran into an iOS bug or if I'm doing something wrong (for example maybe I have to use a specific timezone when dealing with dates from the addressbook and not the user timezone?).

Comment: not 100% sure, but dates coming from the address book (birthdays etc) seem really to be GMT. So I have to care of the timezone and then it seems to work.